# where clause for collection mappings

Tags: mysql, hibernate

Iam trying to get the data from two different tables using where clause. Will i be able to write a where clause on properties of a class which is  mapping.

eg : I have two classes

```
Class box{

private int id;
private String name;
private int colorId;
private int size;

//getter
//setter

}


class color{

private int colorId;
private String colourName;
Private set<box> boxes;



}
```

**mapping :**

```
 <class name="box" table="box">
        <id name="id" column="id">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
     <propert name="name" column="name"/>
     <property name="size" column="size"/>
 </class>

<class name="color" table="color">
        <id name="id" column="id">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
       <propert name="name" column="name"/>
       <set name="boxes" table="box" lazy="false" fetch="join">
        <key><column name="colorId" /></key>
        <one-to-many class="box" not-found="ignore"/>
      </set>
 </class>
```

can i write a HQL like **FROM COLOR where boxes.size > 10**

how can i achieve this useing HQL or any other method. please suggest .

Answer (score 1):

Using HQL you can try...

```
JPA.em().createQuery("SELECT box FROM Color color JOIN color.boxes box where box.size > 10 and color.colorId = ?");
```

So for a giving color, you can get all boxes which have a `size > 10`.
If you want ALL boxes where `box.size > 10`, then you don't need to to the join.